# display random image on each new session?

Tags: php, image, session

I am trying to make it so that each time a user session is loaded a random image is displayed from the directory. Like an advert.

At the moment the image changes each page refresh, this doesn't really help me because as a user goes from page to page the constant refresh of images becomes annoying.

Here's what I have so far?
Please can anyone point out the piece of code I need to do what I need to do.

```
<?php

$path_to_images = "../PTB1/data/adverts/"; // path for images
$default_img = "test.png"; // default image, when error on page

function getRandomImage($path, $img) {

if ( $list = getImagesList($path) ) {
mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 );
$num = array_rand($list);
$img = $list[$num];
}
return $path . $img;
}
function getImagesList($path) {
$ctr = 0;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id']));


if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
// formati slik, ki jih prepozna
if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
$images[$ctr] = $img_file;
$ctr++;
}
}
closedir($img_dir);
return $images;
}
return false;
}

?>
<div class=\"advert-box\" id=\"mod-advert\">
<img src="<?php echo getRandomImage($path_to_images, $default_img) ?>" height="190" width="180"alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: theres about 5 images in a directory, i want one of these to be displayed at random on each user session. and then when the user exits the browser and the goes back to it later its a different random image.

Answer (score 0):

first step, do the image selection when user LOGIN:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['image'])){
    $_SESSION['image'] = getRandomImage($path_to_images, $default_img);
}
```

next, on every page, you just have to look at the `$_SESSION['image']` variable:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['image']; ?>" height="190" width="180"alt="">
```

Comment: is there a way of doing it without the user having to log in? so as soon as they arrive on the page?

Comment: yes, the code I gave you is able to do it. Basically, it check if session data for image is set or not. If it is not there, set it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a **session** variable?

```
<?php 

session_start();
// check if a image is already present
// no need to create again
if(!isset($_session['image'])){
  $_session['image'] = getRandomImage($path_to_images, $default_img);  
}

....
....


<div class=\"advert-box\" id=\"mod-advert\">
<img src="<?php echo $_session['image'] ?>" height="190" width="180"alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks i tried that but now it won't show the images at all :( - seems to be a problem finding the directory now.

Comment: try putting initialization of `$path_to_images` and `$default_img` before or just after `session_start()`